# Apply a function to each row python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert from UTC time to LocaleTime in my dataframe. I have a `dictionary` where I store the number of hours I need to shift for each country code. So for example if I have `df['CountryCode'][0]='AU'` and I have a  `df['UTCTime'][0]=2016-08-12 08:01:00` I want to get `df['LocaleTime'][0]=2016-08-12 19:01:00` which is

```
df['UTCTime'][0]+datetime.timedelta(hours=dateDic[df['CountryCode'][0]])
```

I have tried to do it with a `for loop` but since I have more than 1 million rows it's not efficient. I have looked into the `apply` function but I can't seem to be able to put it to take inputs from two different columns.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @WasiAhmad: I have just done the for loop:


`for i in range(0,len(df['CountryCode'])):

    df['LocaleTime'][i]=df['UTCTime'][i]+datetime.timedelta(hours=dateDic[df['CountryCode'][i]])`

Answer (score 0):

Without having a more concrete example its difficult but try this:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.CountryCode.map(dateDict), 'h') + df.UTCTime
```